# How to resolve `Error: unable to verify the first certificate` while scrapping web page using cheerio?

Tags: reactjs, ssl-certificate

I am trying to learn web scrapping using cheerio. But when I am trying to scrap the content. In one of the site i am getting the following error:

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1515:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:709:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',
```

I am unable to understand as for other sites which i tried to scrap i did not got the error.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const app = express();
const url = "--------------Link Of the site--------------";


axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const articles = [];
        
        $('.text-left a',html).each(function(){
            const title= $(this).text();
            const url= $(this).attr('href');

            articles.push({
                title,
                url    
            })
        })        

        console.log(articles);

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })



app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server running'));
```

Please guide me on how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site on which you get the error is providing an invalid certificate (either the cert itself is wrongly created or damaged, or it doesn't match its claimed issuer); the other sites are providing valid certificates so they don't get this error and instead work correctly.

If the site is publicly accessible (on 443), try using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest to get a pretty thorough analysis with little effort. (It will actually check and display a lot of things about the site's security not only the certificate, but you can ignore the other parts.)

Otherwise or if that doesn't help enough, assuming you have or (can) get OpenSSL, do

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port -servername host -showcerts
# on OpenSSL 1.1.1 up you can omit the -servername host
```

then split apart the certificates in the handshake (the blocks from `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`) into separate files and for at least the first two do

```
openssl x509 -in fileN -text
```

and determine if they appear to chain correctly (first.issuer = second.subject and first.AKI = second.SKI if present) and also test

```
openssl verify -CAfile file2 -partial_chain file1 
# assuming OpenSSL 1.0.2 up; if older post details, this will be much harder
```

PS: you mean scrape/scraping (in context, obtaining information from) not scrap/scrapping (discarding as defective or unusable).