# Error while communication with api and ERROR is : Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Getting error while accessing the SAP URL via google cloud function API.

1. We have a cloud function in GCP
2. We use the intermediate server API(AWS load balancer )to communicate with the SAP PI URL.
3. Now got the error while accessing via AWS load balancer (Intermediate API)

GCP cloud function Logs

[image]

Comment: The certificate chain is incomplete. It means that the API server you are connecting to is misconfigured and did not include the intermediate certificate in the certificate chain it sent to you. Refer this [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265803/) may help in addressing this issue.

Comment: Have you got time to check above. Is your issue addressed?